# Jump to corresponding bracket in Sublime Text

Tags: editor, sublimetext

I am writing big lines of code and then I had to jump from one block of code to another , how would someone jumps to the corresponding opening or closing bracket in the code in sublime text editor.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Before Sublime 3

> Put the cursor on opening or closing tag and Press
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for Windows / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for Mac

Put the cursor on any on the opening or closing bracket and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> , will take your cursor to the respective closing or opening bracket.

#### Sublime 3

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> on Windows

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> on Mac

Comment: Don't forget cmd+m for Mac

Comment: its control + m for Mac on sublime text 3

Comment: Yeah, `cmd`+`m` minimizes windows on Macs.

Comment: Bonus points, it appears you can select the whole thing if you also hold down shift.

Answer (score 7):

The Shortcuts have been updated for Mac on Sublime Text 3

> Put the cursor on opening or closing tag and Press
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for Windows
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for Mac